# How To Upgrade Network Driver To BNX2i

Tags: linux, iscsi, nic

we have a server with a Broadcom NetExtreme II card which supports iSCSI offloading. According to the dell documentation, we need to be running the bnx2i driver to use the iSCSI offloading engine.

We really want to enable offloading as this server is a SAN.

When we query the interface information with `ethtool -i eth0` we get:

```
driver: bnx2
version: 2.1.6
firmware-version: 6.2.12 bc 5.2.3 NCSI 2.0.11
bus-info: 0000:02:00.0
```

What is the best way to go about upgrading to bnx2i?

Comment: Which linux distro? Last time I tried this on Debian Squeeze, it couldn't be done without serious effort, as the drivers were only available for a limited number of platforms.

Comment: Actually openfiler, which runs Red Hat I believe, but rPath distro.

Answer (score 1):

For RHEL 5 and 6, and SLES 10 and 11, you can download the Broadcom drivers from Dell's website under the [Drivers and Downloads](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/driverslist.aspx) section. Alternately, you can download drivers [directly from Broadcom](http://www.broadcom.com/support/ethernet_nic/netxtremeii.php), although I think this will take a little more work to get them going. The documentation for both is fairly reasonable and should take you through building and installing them, assuming they are in fact going to work at all for you.

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing this on openfiler, and tried to compile from the source, but getting an error when I try and install the module `Unknown symbol in module`. Looks like this inst possible, without serious effort.